# not working stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString object-c

Tags: html, objective-c, extract, stringbyevaluatingjavascr

My code:

```
[Web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]]];
    NSString *html = [Web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementsByClassName('bottomwideborder')[1].innerHTML;"];
    NSLog(@"%@", html);
```

Not working for this html file - http://www.mosgortrans.org/pass3/shedule.php?type=avto&way=0&date=0000011&direction=AB&waypoint=1 (I try to extract table from html)

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm supposing you are using Cocoa Touch (iOS), for Cocoa (Mac OS X) it's a bit different. 
loadRequest starts an asynchronous client request. 
You should assign a delegate to your web view that implements `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol and move your code into the `webViewDidFinishLoading` method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.getElementsByClassName('bottomwideborder')[1].innerHTML;"];
    NSLog(@"%@", html);
}
```